# How do i build a JSOn array as mentioned below via GRAILS?

Tags: arrays, json, grails

How do I make a JSON array using grails as follows:

```
{"paymentRequestlist":[{"sourceAccountNo":"555555555555555","sourceBankCode":"GLBBNPKA","destinationBankCode":"GLBBNPKA","destinationBankAccountNo":"123456789111111","corporateName":"","amount":14000,"remarks":"","narrationOne":"fund transfer initiated by maker 1","narrationTwo":"","uniqueId":"ESW-COR:1405491430740"},{"sourceAccountNo":"555555555555555","sourceBankCode":"GLBBNPKA","destinationBankCode":"GLBBNPKA","destinationBankAccountNo":"123456789111111","corporateName":"","amount":13000,"remarks":"","narrationOne":"fund transfer initiated by maker 1","narrationTwo":"","uniqueId":"ESW-COR:1405491430740"}]}
```

So far I have tried to build an array using grails.converters.JSON as follows:

```
JSONArray postParamsArray = new JSONArray()

JSONObject postParams = new JSONObject();
            postParams.put('sourceAccountNo',fundTransfer.fromAccount.accountNumber);
            postParams.put('sourceBankCode',fundTransfer.fromAccount.bank.bankCode);
            postParams.put('destinationBankCode',fundTransfer.toAccount.bank.bankCode);
            postParams.put('destinationBankAccountNo',fundTransfer.toAccount.accountNumber);
            postParams.put('corporateName','');
            postParams.put('amount',fundTransfer.amount);
            postParams.put('remarks','');
            postParams.put('narrationOne',fundTransfer.note);
            postParams.put('narrationTwo','');
            postParams.put('uniqueId',fundTransfer.uniqueId);

 postParamsArray.add(postParams);
```

P.S. I am totally new to grails!!Any Suggestion would be of great help

Answer (score 1):

You can create a map (which is easier) and convert it to JSON

Simple (not tested) example

```
def json = ['paymentRequestlist':[
   ['sourceAccountNo': valueForSourceAccountNo1,
    'sourceBankCode': valueForSourceBankCode1,
    ...
   ],
   ['sourceAccountNo': valueForSourceAccountNo2,
    'sourceBankCode': valueForSourceBankCode2,
    ...
   ]]
] as grails.converters.JSON
```

Answer (score 0):

Complete your code with this:

```
JSONObject completeJson = new JSONObject()
completeJson.put("paymentRequestlist",postParamsArray)

println completeJson as JSON
```